# Python: redirect standard output to a file without using a file handle

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, sys

Can I redirect python print logs to a specific file in each folder in Linux? The requirement is:
I need to run tests in different folders say - fold_1, fold_2, fold_3. All the python files in fold_1 should print to fold_1_py.log, similarly for fold2 and fold_3 logs.
I used a function code shown below:

```
import sys
def Py_print(string):
   sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
   print(string)
   sys.stdout.close()
```

By using the above function, I have to replace all the prints by Py_print(). But instead is something like below pseudo code possible:

```
#for file1 in fold_1
file = os.environ['fold_1_name'] + '_py.log'
sys.stdout = file
```

I need the above code to direct all prints to fold_1_py.log for files in fold_1. Please comment

Answer (score 0):

Got the code for my requirement, the class Logger defined at the end of the below post:
https://www.techiedelight.com/redirect-standard-output-to-file-python/